# How get selected rows where user id is not in table record mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How get selected rows where user id is not in table record

the table like this

table_a

```
id subid userid
1  2     123
2  4     123
```

table_b

```
id title
1  like
2  liked
3  bookmark
4  bookmarked
```

i use join table to get the result 
if WHERE userid=123 then get result

```
id title
2  liked
4  bookmarked
```

the query

```
select b.id,b.title from
table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON b.id = a.subid
WHERE a.userid = '123'
```

but, how if userid = '345' and not in table_a get the result too?.. the result is must like this (selected rows)

```
id title
1  like
3  bookmark
```

Thankyou

Comment: Gve the query that you used

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking

Comment: I doubt you really understand what you are asking? clarify your question first.

Comment: If you're already using a JOIN function you can use LEFT JOIN for still getting the row but without anything in it

Comment: I have clarify my question with query too

Comment: i can't see `id` on `b` - only `no` and `title`!?

Comment: @sebastianbrosch thanks i edit no to id

Comment: @febriqa to be clear do you want result for this specific case or in general you want other results other than current userid where in this case 123

Comment: @SachinDivakar yes by default user that does not exist in a table will get the first and third rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, title FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.subid = t2.id 
WHERE (t1.userid = 345 AND NOT userid IS NULL) OR (
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM t1 WHERE userid = 345) AND userid IS NULL
);
```

The working examples you can find here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a446/25

Comment: thanks for example but the user id='345' should get the selected row,  i have clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query
    select a.no, b.title from a join b on (b.no=a.no) where a.userid='345'

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join and get the data for the table where their is no match. I have solved this recently.
Chk this link:
[Least Popular Event - Get list of events where bookings IS NULL OR LEAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822652/least-popular-event-get-list-of-events-where-bookings-is-null-or-least)

In mysql

```
SELECT b.no,b.title FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.subid = b.no and where a.userid IS NULL;

SELECT b.no,b.title FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.subid = b.no and where a.userid <> '345';
```

in laravel :
    $least = bmodel::leftJoin('a', function($join) 
    {
    $join->on('a.subid', '=', 'b.no');
    })
    ->select('b.no','b.title')
    ->whereNull('a.userid')
    ->first();   or get()

You can use this query to get one or more results. It basically compares userid column with no column and gets list of no and title where there is no match in table a.

Answer (score 0):

> This basically would select with given userId or if that is not present it then selects the result which

```
 SELECT * FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.subid = t2.id WHERE     t1.userid = 123|| 
 (select  userid from t1 where userid =123LIMIT 1) is  null
```

This is the second case where you will get all the rows where it is not 123 or any number

```
 SELECT * FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.subid = t2.id WHERE     t1.userid = 345 || 
 (select  userid from t1 where userid =345 LIMIT 1) is  null
```